# How can i get specific user from identity server - aspNetUsers table depdening on his id

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I try to get one specific user from the `AspNetUsers` table but without success in ASP.Net Core.

Here is the code that i try:

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("employee/{id}")]
    public async Task<Object> GetSpecificUser(string id)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

        return Ok(user);
    }

    // and

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("employee/{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetSpecificUser(string id)
    {
        var user =  _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        return Ok(user);
    }
```

Comment: If neither of those are working, then very literally you do not have a user with that id in your database. Period. Now, as to *why* that user doesn't exist, you might be connected to a different database than you think you are, or there might be some other strangeness going on. However, without more of your code, there's no way to tell.

Comment: First, try to run `_userManager.Users.Tolist()` to see whether there is any user.

Comment: The error was that i have GenderId , in the table ,and it was null,but  with EF it is generated as not null,so the both methods above are working,thank for the reply guys.I write here if somoene serach in future to know that he can use this methods,and that the problem was something else.